# Extern in class function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, icc

My simple code looks like:

a.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace asd
{
    class B
    {
    public:
        void ss()
        {
            extern int i;
            std::cout << i;
        }
    };
}

int main()
{
    asd::B e;
    e.ss();
}
```

b.cpp:

```
int i = 4;
```

Is this code good with standard or no ?
Visual Studio compiles it without errors but the Intel C++ compiler says:
unresolved external symbol "int asd::i" (?i@asd@@3HA)

For more fun if i change b.cpp to:

```
namespace asd
{
    int i = 4;
}
```

Then Visual Studio C++ 2013 says:
unresolved external symbol "int i" (?i@@3HA)

But the Intel C++ compiler says ok :) 
What is the proper version of this code If I want to have this extern in class member function (is it legal ?) ?

Edit:
The best results are, when we change b.cpp to:

```
namespace asd
{
    int i = 4;
}
int i = 5;
```

Visual c++ prints 5, intel compiler 4 :)

Comment: What is this mysterious "other compiler"?

Comment: I compared results with intel compiler. Gcc i didn't test.

Comment: Please show your B.cpp, it compiles with gcc for me.

Comment: So long as the namespace scopes for the definition and declaration match, it should all work. See the answer by @dasblinkenlight

Comment: Ok I reported the bug:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/909772/visual-studio-c-2013-bug-extern-value-in-class-member-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is legal to declare an `extern` or a `static` variable inside any function. Your fix of the `b.cpp` where you put namespace around the definition of that `extern` is the right fix, too.

Visual Studio C++ 2013 complains about a name outside the `asd` namespace (check the [demangler](http://demangler.com/) to see what these extra characters around the name `i` represent). This is incorrect, because the declaration places `i` into the namespace `asd`.

C++ standard illustrates this in section 3.5.7. It is using an `extern` function as an example, but it illustrates the rule of placement of the name in the enclosing namespace.

```
namespace X {
    void p() {
        q(); // error: q not yet declared
        extern void q(); // q is a member of namespace X
    }
    void middle() {
        q(); // error: q not yet declared
    }
    void q() { /* ... */ } // definition of X::q
}
void q() { /* ... */ } // some other, unrelated q
```

The comments on lines 4, 9, and 11 show that the name declared with `extern` inside the member function needs to be placed in the enclosing namespace. It is a good, self-contained test case illustrating a bug in Microsoft's compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Visual Studio is wrong.

This is what I found in the draft standard:

> 3.3.2/10
>
> Function declarations at block scope and variable declarations with the `extern` specifier at block scope refer to declarations that are members of an enclosing namespace, but they do not introduce new names into that scope.

Having said that, I would move the `extern` declaration out of the function and into the namespace to see if that makes any difference.

```
namespace asd
{
    extern int i;
    class B
    {
    public:
        void ss()
        {
            std::cout << i;
        }
    };
}
```